# How to host Blazor server app in IIS's sub folder?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor-server-side

I want to deploy a Blazor server app in IIS's sub folder. I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#publish-the-app to set appbasepath.

hosted url: http://localhost/testApp

Resources are loading correctly as `http://localhost/testApp/css/style.css` like that.
It loads login page, after successful login i redirect to index page using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/index")`.

The Url must be http://localhost/testApp/index   but the url become http://localhost/index so it is failed to load a page.  I troubleshoot and found if i pass `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/testApp/index")`  then it works as expected. But I worried then i need to forcibly append this /testApp to point other URLs.

Could anyone please assist to host blazor server app in IIs sub folder.

Comment: Tried your comment. It loads Url as http://localhost/testApp/~/index   It is not loads page.

Comment: I tried this, NavigationManager.NavigateTo("~/index");

Comment: I tried NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/~/index");   it loads url as http://localhost/~/index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220996/discussion-between-ajumobi-olamide-and-nithya-neela).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, you've found the answer to the question by now, but just in case, if it is still of interest to someone - you should remove leading "/" in the .NavigateTo.

Comment: Just wondering whether it works also when running app in root (not in subfolder)

Comment: I did not test it on the site, hosted in IIS root, but it worked for me in following cases:
1. While debugging app from VS (it kind-of hosted in the root when you do that)
2. In IIS with app, hosted in the dedicated virtual directory on IIS